# Combine Multiple Rows into One Row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am studying Pandas and I have this dataframe:

**Source Dataframe:**
[image: Source Dataframe]

And I want to combine the same value within the same date into one row like this:

**Result Dataframe:**
[image: Result Dataframe]

How to do it the most efficient way?

Thank you.

Comment: Your source dataframe is probably the result of a bad pivot. You should fix it before or use `df.groupby('Time').agg('first')`

Answer (score 0):

Just simple:

```
df.groupby('Time').sum()
```

Comment: Which is better using the .agg('first') or the .sum() method?

Comment: It depends on the source and the desired output (what kind of logic do you want to use). These two methods give the same output for your dataframe.

Comment: My concern is NaN with the .sum() method. So it's possible for eg. 9 + NaN = 9?